# Serializing multiple Objects

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

```
class AppDataManager
{
    public static async Task SaveAsync<T>(T data, string fileName)
    {
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, 
            CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.WriteObject(stream ,data);
        await stream.FlushAsync();
    }

    public static async Task<T> RestoreAsync<T>(string fileNa me)
    {
        try
        {
            var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

            var instream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(instream);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}


    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        await AskUserToLocalDataAsync();

        if (useLocalData)
        {
           SomethingGoesHere  = await AppDataManager.RestoreAsync<UserData>(fileName);
        }
    }
```

the code works fine, but it return only one Object, I want to write multiple objects and retrieve it as an observableCollection to bind it to a GridView. the GenerateUniqueName is to append multiple objects wright ?

how to store it ? and how to retrieve it ?

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with a property that will hold your collection. Then serialize that class.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a `Collection` class for your objects.

For example a `Widget` object:

```
[DataContract]
public class Widget
{
  [DataMember]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

You could then make a `WidgetCollection` class:

```
[DataContract]
public class WidgetCollection
{
  [DataMember]
  public List<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
}
```

You can serialize/deserialize the `WidgetCollection` and then `foreach` through and add to an `ObservableCollection<Widget>`.

Also, wrap your `IDisposable` objects (like `IRandomAccessStream`) in `using` statements so they get properly disposed.